# SSH from Windows CL to RPi4

Tags: pi-4, ssh, windows

I've been trying to find a way to use my Yubikey to ssh from Windows to my RPi, but I can't seem to find a way. When I use a Kali VM, I am able to use the ssh-keygen -t ed25519-sk command and this allows me to generate keys and authenticate myself on Kali using my Yubikey instead of a password. However, on Window it seems like the only passwordless option is by using Putty and generating SSH keys. Do you guys know any way to use the Yubikey on Windows?

Thanks!

Comment: that would be a windows question, not a raspberry pi question